# Seemingly locked in console after CTRL+ALT+F1 --- How to quit?

Tags: command-line

I got into console login page by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and I don't want to reset the PC.

<kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> weren't enough to get back to the desktop environment. How could I get back to the desktop environment?

Thanks,

Comment: You were in a [pseudo] terminal; something I love about *nix (unix, posix, or gnu/linux). Unix was created in the early 70s when text terminals were king, and Ubuntu GNU/Linux contains the old heritage. You'll discover you can hit ctrl+alt+f2 for term 2, +f3 for term 3 etc. The number of [pseudo] terminals can be altered, but usually +f7 gets you to GUI (as per answer, though in certain circumstances its +F8, and +F1 for some configs) but its configurable.  If you GUI is slow, switching to a terminal can let you explore why without further stressing the gui by opening a gui-term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to the Desktop.

Comment: Hmm I mistakenly clicked twice and now has a black screen... What can be done?

Comment: ESC than CTRL+ALT+F7 again helped. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. It fooled me too my first time in Ubuntu many moons ago. As you are new I should point out clicking the check mark next to the answer lets others know it works. Of course you can always post a better answer or wait for one and then accept that too.

Comment: In the past, occasionally the desktop would appear on TTY8 (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F8`) instead.